# WP + Superfish: Parent Menu Item not keeping text-shadow while children are being hovered

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, superfish

As the title suggests... I'm setting up a superfish menu using the Wordpress CSS Dropdown Menu plugin, and my parent menu item isn't keeping the hover's `text-shadow`.. I've setup a jsfiddle to help express the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/e6uUs/1/

Help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding the solution eventually, I needed to set the style for `ul li:hover a` thanks for the help though. :)